# How to fix "Reference Error: message is not defined" in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js, I have a requirement of parsing request body in the file named 'message.txt'. Which works fine when I logged the message variable on the console. The code is simple, first, it creates a server then receives a request on the post method then saves it to the file named 'message.txt'. I have tried to change the variable name but still, the error can't be solved.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
   const url= req.url;
   const method = req.method;
   if(url=='/'){
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>enter message</title><head>');
    res.write('<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">submit</button></form></body>');
    res.write('</html>');
   return res.end();
   }
  if(url=='/message'&&method=='POST'){
    const body =[];
    req.on('data',(chunk)=>{
      body.push(chunk);
      console.log(body)
    });
    req.on('end',()=>{
      const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
     // console.log(parsedBody);
    const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
    //console.log(messsage)
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('message.txt',message);
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location','/')
    return res.end();
  }
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   res.write('<html>');
   res.write('<head><title>my first page!</title><head>');
   res.write('<body><h1>hello from node js</h1></body>');
   res.write('</html>');
   res.end();
  });    
server.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using local defined `message` variable out of the callback function. Even if you define this var globally there is poor likelihood the variable won't have `NULL` value during passing it to `fs.writeFileSync`.

So just specify your `fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message);` withing `req.on('end', () => { ... }` after the line you define the `message` var.

Answer (score 1):

`If` block should be like

```
if(url=='/message'&&method=='POST'){
    const body =[];
    req.on('data',(chunk)=>{
      body.push(chunk);
      console.log(body)
    });
    var message = '';
    req.on('end',()=>{
      const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
     // console.log(parsedBody);
    message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
    //console.log(messsage)
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('message.txt',message);
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location','/')
    return res.end();
  }
```

Basically your `message` variable's scope was limited to `req.on()` and thus not accessible outside.

Answer (score 1):

Constant variables are block scoped, [read more about them here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

In your code, there is this piece:

```
req.on('end',()=>{
    const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    // console.log(parsedBody);
    const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
    //console.log(messsage)
});
fs.writeFileSync('message.txt',message);
```

Here, you are passing an arrow function as a callback on the second argument of `req.on`.
This arrow function has it's own `block scope`.

By declaring the `message` variable within that block scope, you won't be able to access it outside of it.

And, on the next line you where you call `fs.writeFileSync` you are trying to do just that, accessing the `message` variable which doesn't exist in that scope.

Thus, move that line in the scope:

```
req.on('end',() => {
    const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
    fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message); // here message can be accessed
});
```